# Is there a way to pass basic auth header options when retrieving a deck.gl layer?

Tags: deck.gl

I am looking to create an MVTLayer from a private repository that is wrapped with a basic authorization header.  I was looking through the source code and don't see a way to pass additional header options to the POST.  Is there a way to pass a header when retrieving a deck.gl layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `loadOptions` property of `MVTLayer`. Anything you pass in there will get passed through to the native `fetch`.

For example,

```
const myLayer = new MVTLayer({
  // ...
  loadOptions:
    fetch: {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa('login:password'))
      }
    }
  }
});
```

see example here:
https://deck.gl/docs/developer-guide/loading-data